# How to deal with whitespaces when reading a file with a scanner

Tags: java

I am writing a program where I read data from a file name that the user inputs using a scanner. I am making a new object from each line of the file using the following code:

```
 while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] parts = line.split(" ");
        //create new object from parts here 
}
```

This works correctly until my file for .txt files where there is no whitespace in between the lines but when there is a blank line in between words it stops working entirely.

Right now it only works on a .txt file set up like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I want to set it up to read a file like this:

```
line 1

line 2

line 3
```

How can I modify my program to read over a blank line and check if there is text after it?

Comment: Split on multiple new lines? `scan.useDelimiter("\\n(\\s*\\n)?")`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I want to create a new object from each individual line of text. Would this work in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the first value in your parts array, which will always exist.

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    if (!parts[0].isEmpty()) {
        //create new object from parts here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the library `StringUtils` from apache and use the method `StringUtils.isBlank(line)` it gives back a boolean: true if the string is empty or has only a blank space or false if the string is not empty.

Otherwise you can do a manual check:

```
if (line != null || line.equals("") || line.equals(" "))    
  continue;
```

This will skip to next line if the actual line is empty.

Comment: Note that there is `isEmpty()` and `isBlank()` in standard Java already. No need for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom delimiter and call `hasNext()` and `next()`.

I added a static parse method that takes the current line, splits it, and then calls the POJO constructor.

#### `App.java`

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    private static class Pojo {
        private String text;
        private int number;
        
        protected Pojo(String text, int number) {
            this.text = text;
            this.number = number;
        }
        
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{ \"text\": \"%s\", \"number\": %d }", text, number);
        }
    }
    
    private static Pojo parseLine(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.trim().split(" ");
        return new Pojo(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = App.class.getClassLoader();
        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/data.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\n(\\s*\\n)?");

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            Pojo pojo = parseLine(scan.next());
            System.out.println(pojo);
        }
        
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

#### `resources/data.txt`

```
line 1


line 2


line 3
```

### Output

```
{ "text": "line", "number": 1 }
{ "text": "line", "number": 2 }
{ "text": "line", "number": 3 }
```